# Trigger gitlab ci/cd job on commandline

Tags: git, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

We have a bunch of gitlab CI/CD jobs defined in a git repository. They run fine on the gitlab server (UI Web interface), but my question is: Is there a way to trigger such a job via the (Linux) commandline ?

Answer (score -1):

By default, your CI/CD pipeline will be triggered when you push any file (via the command line, or otherwise) to your repository. However, you can configure it to run by [calling a trigger](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/triggers/README.html) or [webhooks](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/integrations/webhooks.html) (which trigger pipelines when certain specified actions are taken).